# SQLException: No suitable Driver Found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss, ojdbc

I am trying to develop a Java EE application that connect to an `Oracle` database from eb service class but I encounter a

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
```

I have the `ojdbc6.jar` in the class path and I have also verified that this in the `JBoss` deployment folder.

My application `EAR` is composed of a `WAR`. What is wrong (root cause) with this? Please help.

Connection URL in persistence.xml:

```
> "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl"
```

Stack Trace:

```
16:06:32,687 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default-workqueue-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a80106:-3e8b2d6f:5037338f:15, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@4d1082 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 70 more

16:06:32,796 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (default-workqueue-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component CreditcardFacade for method public abstract void com.peter.ejb.CreditcardFacadeLocal.addCreditCard(com.peter.entity.Creditcard): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.peter.ejb.CreditcardFacadeLocal$$$view2.addCreditCard(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at $Proxy96.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:144) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:127) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2827) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 70 more

16:06:32,953 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default-workqueue-1) Application {http://service.peter.com/}CreditCardServiceService#{http://service.peter.com/}addCreditCard has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Transaction rolled back
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:155) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:86) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:121) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:61) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:232) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor$1.run(OneWayProcessorInterceptor.java:109) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$2.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:332) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.peter.ejb.CreditcardFacadeLocal$$$view2.addCreditCard(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at com.peter.service.CreditCardService.addCreditCard(CreditCardService.java:56) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:173) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89) [cxf-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1481) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at $Proxy96.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:144) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:127) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2827) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 70 more
```

Oracle Database Version: 11.2.0.

Does driver version need to match with database version?

EDIT:

1. How to trace which file path the program load the driver from? This enhance me to find the root cause. Thanks.
2. How to enable the ojdbc6-g logging? I'm tried follow this [Oracle_JDBC](http://lokeshtc.blogspot.com/2012/01/enabling-and-using-jdbc-logging.html)
   but I do not know how to complete it. How to set the java system property globally?
   I know that environment variable may not a good choice. Any other idea? 
   I just want to add -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true and -Djava.util.logging.config.file to jvm creation when using this java. Is it set up oracle database during the startup?
3. How to enable hibernate logging?
4. I'm using Hibernate-4.1.1 and JBoss 7.1.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide full error stack trace and connection URL

Comment: Which version of Oracle database you are trying to connect?

Comment: Information provded in edited post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "ojdbc.jar" is not in the `CLASSPATH` of your application server.

Just tell us which application server it is and we will tell you where the driver should be placed.

**Edit**: I saw the tag [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss) so it has to be placed in folder `"$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/"`

Comment: I using JBoss 7.1 AS. The ojdbc6.jar is exists in the $JBOSS_Home/standalone/deployments/appName/Web-INF/lib. I tried to copy the ojdbc6.jar to $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/lib but the error still exists. How to trace which file path the program load the driver from? This enhance me to find the root cause. Thanks.

Comment: in your boot.log file, you should see java.class.path as follow 10:41:16,818 DEBUG [ServerInfo]     java.class.path: :./../server/default/mycompany_configfiles:/var/lib/jboss/myenvironment/bin/run.jar:/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_23_amd64//lib/tools.jar:/var/lib/jboss/myenvironment/lib/jboss-logmanager.jar - and most of this all the environment variables are display at startup just after launching it. hope this could help

Comment: To avoid to add a new answer here is a link to the log my jBoss produces : https://gist.github.com/3462417

Comment: I had checked the java.class.path which pointed to JBoss_HOME\jboss-modules.jar. I would like to add another class path which point to lib. How can i edit the classpath from standalone.bat or standalone.conf.bat?

Comment: This method was applicable to JBoss versions before AS 7. It's not the way it works as of JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6 / WildFly 8...

Comment: Just going to add that if you need to download a driver for oracle DB you can find it here

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-21-1-c-downloads.html

Answer (score 9):

"No suitable driver" usually means that the `JDBC` URL you've supplied to connect has incorrect syntax or when the driver isn't loaded at all.

When the method getConnection is called, the `DriverManager` will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.(using `Class.forName()`)

For Example

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.­OracleDriver");
```

Also check that you have `ojdbc6.jar` in your classpath. I would suggest to place `.jar` at physical location to JBoss `"$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/"` directory of your project.

EDIT:

You have mentioned `hibernate` lately.

Check that your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file has connection properties something like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">scott</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">tiger</property>
```

Comment: The ojdbc6.jar is add to the project already otherwise it will fail on deployment time.

Comment: Funny disgusting thing here. String `jdbc:oracle:thin` copypasted through microsoft lync became `jdbc:Oracle:thin` because microsoft thinks `:o` is a smiley and should look like `:O`

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it is the simple things. In my case, I had an invalid url. 
I had left out a colon before the at sign (@).
I had "jdbc:oracle:thin@//localhost" instead of "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost"
Hope this helps someone else with this issue.

Comment: Just FYI the "at sign" @ is called an asperand, not an asterisk.

Comment: This & is an ampersand. This * (super-scripted) is an asterisk. This @ is an "at sign". (I am sure it has another name but it is not "asperand".)

Comment: @jrdevdba LMAO. "Asperand"?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Loool sorry about that! I have no idea how I bungled that spelling. I heard the word in my head and had known it for years. facepalm....

Answer (score 2):

For me I did enter a invalid url like : `orcl` only instead of `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl`

Answer (score 2):

First, if you develop an application with Java EE 6 within a server (JBoss),
you should better use a [DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html). Then you can obtain the Connection from this DataSource. It's better to use connections pools.

Then, as of JBoss AS 7, the JDBC driver must be declared as a module.
This is described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1).

With OJDBC 6 (11.x), the name of the driver should be "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver".
This is the name registered in SPI mode (see the content of this file : *META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver*).
Since Java 6 and JDBC 4.0, the JDBC Drivers are **auto-registered**.

Finally you will have to declare a DataSource within JBoss : [DataSource configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration).

References :

- **Establishing a Connection** ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)) (JDBC 4.0 <=> Java 6)
- **JDBC 4.0 Enhancements in Java SE 6 > Auto-Loading of JDBC Driver** ([link](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html))

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
set classpath=%classpath%(ur jarfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Download JDBC driver and add to libraries.
Download link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. I had all the required jars as well.

[Please refer code screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VthEK.png)

But after adding

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

it worked for me.

```
package com.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class TestJdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe";
        String user ="SYSTEM";
        String password = "root";
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to DAtabase");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  /*added this line*/
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println( connection.toString());
            System.out.println("Connection Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**NOTE :** IF YOU ARE USING JDK 8 TRY TO USE ***OJDBC8*** instead of ***OJDBC14*** in that case you will not have to add Class.forName as well.

Comment: @deepesh Saraswat you can include code in the answer instead of putting screenshots.

Comment: @Deepak  Done  . Please check the updated reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix it in Jboss 7 AS, I copy the oracle driver jar file to Jboss module folder. Example: `../jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/hibernate/main`.

You also need to change "module.xml"

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="asm.asm"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="org.antlr"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    <module name="org.infinispan" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.javassist"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="4" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.envers" services="import" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error so for that
First the **Oracle URL is correct or not like**
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

Then also you can give the OJDBC6.jar to buildpath at project level and also
you copy this jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder if you are working with tomcat.

and also use the Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); to explicitly load the Driver class.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ users, here is what helped me:
*Run Configuration/ Modify options/ Add dependencies with provided scope to classpath*

This way IntelliJ can recognize the JDBC library.

Answer (score -1):

i have changed my old path: jdbc:odbc:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

to new : jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl

and it worked for me.....hurrah!!
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be8yL.png)