# Oracle Driver not found

Tags: eclipse, oracle, tomcat

My tomcat web app isn't loading the oracle driver any longer.  I moved tomcat and messed with the server definition.  Its up and running but can't connect to Oracle due to a missing driver.

I had similar problem with log4j and other libs but adding the lib into the Deployment Assembly of the web app properties solved those issues.

The Oracle lib is there as is its odbc6.jar.

I also tried copying it to WEB-INF/lib with to no avail.

I have a hunch this is a class path problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I'm also concerned that tomcat can find other libs but not the oracle liv.

[SQLException: No suitable Driver Found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103369/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin-localhost1521-or)

Comment: Where's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I also tried adding the oracle lib to the classpath and restarting everything.  no luck

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  I removed the server from the eclipse server window.  Clean the project.  Added the server back in.  Cleaned and rebuild and it worked.

Comment: Actually I think what did the trick was after editing the Server run time location in the preferences window I pressed "download and install" which I believe reset the location information.  After that all worked fine.