# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to create a connection to my database(oracle), when I put test my code using the main method, it works seamlessly. 
However, when trying to access it through Tomcat 8, it fails with error:
No suitable driver found for "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe"
I have added ojdbc6 jar file to lib and also configured the built path. 
The url,use, password is correct still it give the above error.
when i paste the same code in main it runs but in tomcat it doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12103369/18157

Comment: PLEASE at least type your error message into a Google search before posting here.  This has been answered countless times on StackOverflow and other forums.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `ojdbc6.jar` file in tomcat/lib folder or in your application lib `<Aplication>/WEB-INF/lib` to get it work.