# Unable to deploy war on one particular server

Tags: maven, spring-boot, war, ojdbc, noraui

I have a spring-boot project.I have created a war file , i am deploying it on 2 linux based tomcat servers and 1 windows based tomcat server , The file is deployed successfully on 1 linux based server and windows based server but fails on 1 of the linux based server

Tried changing the dependency in pom

Below is the snippet from pom.xml currently using

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

previously i was using below scope and systempath

```
 <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
 <version>7</version>
 <scope>system</scope>
 <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/oracle/ojdbc/7/ojdbc-7.jar</systemPath>
```

still i am getting java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin on 1 particular linux server

Please provide suggestions , if any ,stuck since yesterday

Snippet from stacktrace is as below

```
2017-10-18 15:01:29.862 DEBUG 34036 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
15:01:29.862 [DEBUG] o.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2017-10-18 15:01:42.347  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
15:01:42.347 [INFO ] c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker - [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2017-10-18 15:01:42.402  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Hazelcast 3.7 (20160817 - 1302600) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5701
15:01:42.402 [INFO ] c.h.system - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Hazelcast 3.7 (20160817 - 1302600) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5701
2017-10-18 15:01:42.403  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
15:01:42.403 [INFO ] c.h.system - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2017-10-18 15:01:42.404  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
15:01:42.404 [INFO ] c.h.system - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2017-10-18 15:01:43.217  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Backpressure is disabled
15:01:43.217 [INFO ] c.h.s.i.o.i.BackpressureRegulator - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Backpressure is disabled
2017-10-18 15:01:45.730 DEBUG 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Updating members [Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 9daa0612-f3dc-4eaa-9b29-06e4b11c225a this]
15:01:45.730 [DEBUG] c.h.i.c.ClusterService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Updating members [Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 9daa0612-f3dc-4eaa-9b29-06e4b11c225a this]
2017-10-18 15:01:45.731 DEBUG 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService         : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 9daa0612-f3dc-4eaa-9b29-06e4b11c225a this
15:01:45.731 [DEBUG] c.h.i.p.InternalPartitionService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Adding Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - 9daa0612-f3dc-4eaa-9b29-06e4b11c225a this
2017-10-18 15:01:45.815  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTING
15:01:45.815 [INFO ] c.h.c.LifecycleService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTING
2017-10-18 15:01:46.387  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Starting 4 partition threads
15:01:46.387 [INFO ] c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationExecutorImpl - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Starting 4 partition threads
2017-10-18 15:01:46.391  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Starting 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
15:01:46.391 [INFO ] c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationExecutorImpl - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Starting 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2017-10-18 15:01:46.407  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
15:01:46.407 [INFO ] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2017-10-18 15:01:46.410 DEBUG 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] IO threads selector mode is SELECT
15:01:46.410 [DEBUG] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] IO threads selector mode is SELECT
2017-10-18 15:01:46.438  WARN 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
15:01:46.438 [WARN ] c.h.i.Node - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
2017-10-18 15:01:46.569  INFO 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED
15:01:46.569 [INFO ] c.h.c.LifecycleService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED
profile:dev
property file lookup
2017-10-18 15:01:50.998  WARN 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
15:01:50.998 [WARN ] o.a.t.j.p.PooledConnection - Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
2017-10-18 15:01:51.025 ERROR 34036 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@mumchora65:1821:STAGE
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:873)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at com.crisil.quantix.config.DatabaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(DatabaseConfiguration.java:109)
    at com.crisil.quantix.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61a361cf.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$5(<generated>)
    at com.crisil.quantix.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61a361cf$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5775aed4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com.crisil.quantix.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61a361cf.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:215)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

15:01:51.025 [ERROR] o.a.t.j.p.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@mumchora65:1821:STAGE
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:873)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
```

Comment: share the stacktrace also. It seems like your war either doesn't have the required jar or there may be a conflict. You may have the ojdbc jar also in tomcat lib folder. And look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103369/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin-localhost1521-or

Comment: I am co-creator of com.github.noraui, this jar file is deprecated, please use this sample: github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in question it is a spring-boot project. I was running the war with dev profile on 1 server and sit profile on another server .

JDBC drives were not properly configured on 1 of the server that was the root cause after configuring the drives in application.yml . it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check that this jar `/lib/oracle/ojdbc/7/ojdbc-7.jar` is also found from the failing servers *tomcat.home*/lib in the same path.

If not, add it there, restart tomcat see if it deploys ok.

You can also change dependencys scope to compile, which is not good idea if the jar is found in other servers.

Answer (score 0):

I am co-creator of com.github.noraui, this jar file is deprecated, please use this sample: github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc