# No suitable driver found for "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" in hibernate without IDE

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, ojdbc

I am using Hibernates without any IDE. I doing on notepad++ text editor. I follow all the steps and worked fine. I set all the jars as classpath. i set classpath foe ojdbc14.jar for my jdk 1.8.0_15. When i run my java file hibernates gives the below error.

`No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe`

I use the below line in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
..
...
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>  
..
..
</session-factory>
```

help me to how to resolve this no suitable driver found?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLException: No suitable Driver Found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103369/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin-localhost1521-or)

Comment: setting all the path and classpath fine. But i dont know where did i do wrong?

Comment: Hai @StefanFreitag, I am not using any Server like Tomcat, JBOSS.. I am just doing a static way of creating xml files, and .java files. Is this really required any Server to work on Hibernate?

Comment: @BaluKompalli are you sure ojdbc.jar in in the classpath when you run your application?

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, when you say you "follow[ed] all the steps and [it] worked fine," there's no way for us to spot a mistake if you don't tell us what steps you followed. How, exactly, did you set up your CLASSPATH?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ojdbc14.jar`, that is ancient (for Java 1.4). Please upgrade to a newer version of the driver. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: Hai MarsAtomic, I followed all the steps  from this link "https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application" and set all the jars to the classpath. Downloaded all the hibernate jars and set those jars in the classpath variable. I am using Windows8.1 OS.

Comment: Hai @Ivan, yes, I set the ojdbc.jar in the classpath. and this jar is worked fine in jdbc connections.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, But this ojdbc14.jar is worked fine for jdbc connections. Why it is not suitable for Hibernate?could you please tell me?

Comment: You should not be using ancient version of a driver. There are newer versions that 1) have bugs fixed, 2) support newer database features, and 3) support newer JDBC features (eg like JDBC driver auto-loading, which was introduced in Java 6). That last example (driver auto-loading) may well be the problem here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Which is suitable ojdbc.jar for jdk1.8?

Comment: See the link in my first comment...